# rk1000 codec read/write i2c wait event timeout in Android 4.4.2

Tags: android, audio

I have one question about rk1000-s codec read/write operation i2c wait event timeout of Android 4.4.2
  The system is RK3188+RK1000 TV box design. Sound output devices is RK29_RK1000 & Rockchip-spdif. RK1000-s codec controlled by i2c.4 bus. When system bootup, there are much i2c error messages like,

```
rk30_i2c rk30_i2c.4: Addr[0x006c] wait event timeout, state:0, is_busy:1, error:0, complete_what:0x2, ipd:0x20.
rk30_i2c rk30_i2c.4: I2C_CON: start bit is set.

Does anyone encounter similar issues on Rockchip platform? What is the reason and how can I fix these problems.
```

Thanks a lot.